# Как настроить маршрутизацию для двух сетевых карт с внешними ip?

Tags: ubuntu, сервер, ip, маршрутизация

Имеется сервер с двумя сетевыми картами. В обе карты заходят два внешних *IP* (разные подсети и маски).

Как сделать, чтобы извне их можно было пинговать одновременно?

Прописываю маршрут `route add -net 0.0.0.0 netmask 0.0.0.0 gw x.x.x.x dev p1p1`, пинг на первую сетевую идет, на вторую — нет, и наоборот.

Comment: Вы точно пингуете с внешнего ресурса?

Comment: да, пинговал отсюда http://ping.eu/ping/, еще и с соседнего компьютера

Answer (score 2):

первое, что я бы порекомендовал — удалить пакет *network-manager*: он облегчает настройку сети в тривиальных ситуациях и лишь мешает в нетривиальных.

настройка маршриутизации для разных нетривиальных случае хорошо описана в документе, известном под названием [*lartc*](http://www.lartc.org/). есть и переводы на русский, например на [opennet](http://www.opennet.ru/docs/RUS/LARTC/LARTC-net.html.gz). в частности, про настройку маршрутизации для двух провайдеров написано в [разделе 4.2](http://www.opennet.ru/docs/RUS/LARTC/x348.html).

есть неплохая (на вид) [пошаговая инструкция по настройке балансировки](http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/ip_balancing) между двумя провайдерами (тремя несколько разными способами).

Comment: Network-manager и не был установлен, у меня Ubuntu server

Comment: *network-manager* — это, вообще-то, демон, получающий информацию об изменении состояния сетевых интерфейсов и производящий их [ре]конфигурацию. вы, вероятно, имеете в виду одну из множества *gui-обёрток* для управления этим демоном. но им можно управлять и из *cli*. / а *ubuntu-сервер* отличается от *ubuntu-destop* по большей части лишь количеством пакетов, распаковываемых при установке.

Comment: network-manager, systemd, pulseaudio - криворукая попытка некоего Л. П. преваратить Линукс в филиал форточки.